# How does an "alert()" function execute in a variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables

```js
var a = 'hello'-alert('hi'); // a is Not-a-Number and pops up 'hi'
var b = 'world';-alert('ok'); // b is 'world' and pops up 'ok'
```

Can some one explain me how does the *alert()* in these variable works?
It seems weird as both of the *alert()*-s are in a variable.

Comment: What do you mean by _they are in a variable_? The first one just subtracts the result of the call, the second one negates the result but then ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

With `a`, `substruction` expect the two operators to be numbers, else the result will be `NaN` ( Not a Number ), and as `alert` is a `void` function it will return `undefined`.

With `b`, the `;` will end the `b` variable declaration so it's value will be `world`.

Answer (score 0):

The expression on the right hand side of the assignment is evaluated before the assignment happens.

So, for `a`, the `alert` function is called and whatever its return value is is "subtracted" from the string `"hello"` and that result is stored in `a`.

For, `b`, the string `"world"` is assigned and then the statement after the semi-colon is executed.